# when to use but and when to use and

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

What you would use here, but or and? "beating them" is a new idea or exception of the first idea?

**There are several effective ways to discipline a preschooler, but\and beating them is completely inhuman.**

Also more examples will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

'**But**' is a conjunction that is used to introduce a statement or clause that will be *in contrast or different* from what has already been mentioned.

'**And**' is a conjunction that is used to connect statements or clauses that are *similar*.

In your example, the conjunction 'but' would be better. The speaker is contrasting disciplining a preschooler with being completely inhuman. As a native American speaker this sentence sounds natural and better conveys the intended idea:

> There are several effective ways to discipline a preschooler, but
>   beating them is completely inhuman.

You could also use the word '**however**' in place of 'but'.